# Word-counting script in C#

Tags: c#, strings, sorting, regex, hash-map

My goal is to read from standard input, break up the input into words (Unicode letters and apostrophes), case-insensitively, and produce a report to standard output, where each line is a word followed by a space followed by its count. The output should be sorted by words.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class TraditionalWordCountApp
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SortedDictionary<string, int> counts = new SortedDictionary<string, int>();
        Regex wordRegex = new Regex(@"[\p{L}']+");
        string line;
        while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            line = line.ToLower();
            foreach (Match m in wordRegex.Matches(line))
            {
                String word = m.Value;
                int count;
                counts.TryGetValue(word, out count);
                counts[word] = ++count;
            }
        }
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in counts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

My concerns:

- Should things be wrapped in a namespace?
- Should either the class or the `main` function or both be `public`?
- Is there a nicer way to declare the sorted dictionary? Java has `<>`, does C#?
- I used the C-style idiom of assigning to a variable and then checking for null, all inside the while-condition! Surely there is a nicer way to do this in C#. Is there? I like neither the embedded assignment nor the billion-dollar-mistake `null`. :)
- I searched StackOverflow a bit for a nicer way to update a word frequency dictionary. Most languages seem to have a built-in get-with-default method on dictionaries, but the answers I saw said no, and they recommended `TryGetValue`. These answers are old, though. Is there something nicer in the most modern C#?
- Any nicer way to do the last loop?
- Would a LINQ-based solution be nicer? More idiomatic? What would it look like? I *think* (though I am brand new to C#) I could whip something up, but should I? FWIW I [do know how to do the LINQ-y stuff in Java](https://github.com/rtoal/polyglot/blob/master/java/WordCountApp.java) but wonder if this is the right way to go in C#.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. It's not mandatory but it's a widely accepted guideline. Break it only if you have a good reason to do so.
2. No, they don't. Class should be `internal` (default) and `static` (because it has not instance methods). `Main()` method should be private to make clear that it won't be called outside this class but it's not mandatory (someone prefers `public` because it's *logically* called from outside).

For the other points things are more complex that a paragraph...

You can create a *generator* to read from standard input (see very last paragraph for a discussion about this):

```
private static IEnumerable<string> ReadAllInputs()
{
    while (true)
    {
        string line = Console.ReadLine();
        if (line == null)
            break;

        yield return line;
    }
}
```

You do not need `ToLower()` on input, I do not even start to mention all the problems of **case insensitive comparison** if not done properly: a lower case string may be different from an upper case string (even in number of characters) but they may be compared equal. Don't put yourself in trouble and let the framework do the work for you:

```
var counts = new SortedDictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Note that you do not need a `SortedDictionary` here, ordering may be done (in this case) when printing output. If performance matters then you should profile by yourself.

When you increment word count you also increment local variable `count`, not a big performance hit (and compiler may be smart enough to elide local variable) but it's about code clarity. You can do:

```
counts[word] = count + 1;
```

Or simply:

```
++counts[word];
```

Note that this *innocent* code `++counts[word]` (as well as original `counts[word] = ++count`) when `word` doesn't exist in dictionary (`TryGetValue` returns `false`) will perform another lookup vanishing part of the benefit of `TryGetValue` for the first insertion! You have to explicitly call `Add()`.

If you want you can refactor `foreach` loop to print results with LINQ, not a big gain (IMO), let's see how:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
    counts.Select(x => $"{x.Key} {x.Value}")));
```

If we put everything together with then have something like this:

```
namespace Test {
    static class TraditionalWordCountApp {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var counts = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
            var wordRegex = new Regex(@"(?i)[\p{L}']+");

            foreach (var match in ReadAllInputs().SelectMany(x => wordRegex.Match(x))) {
                if (counts.TryGetValue(match.Value, out count))
                    counts[word] = count + 1;
                else
                    counts.Add(match.Value, 1);    
            }

            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                counts.OrderBy(x => x.Key).Select(x => $"{x.Key} {x.Value}")));
        }

        static IEnumerable<string> ReadAllInputs() {
            while (true) { // Yes, in C# this is "safe"
                string line = Console.ReadLine();
                if (line == null)
                    break;

                // No need to match any regex against an empty line
                if (line.Length == 0)
                    continue; 

                yield return line;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

All these done you may think that...there should be another way to do it. You can use `GroupBy()`. Profile both versions to see which one has better performance (and the one you feel more easy to understand):

```
var counts = ReadAllInputs()
    .SelectMany(x => regex.Match(x))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Value, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    .Select(x => new { Word = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Word);
```

Then you print it with:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
    counts.Select(x => $"{x.Word} {x.Count}")));
```

---

One final note about *word counting*. It may apply or not to your case but don't forget that *word* is a concept with different meanings in different languages. Topic is vast but try to paste a - for example - Japanese text in Microsoft Word and check what the word count is: number of *characters* (another *vague* concept). If you have to deal with international text you may need to write specific code for different cultures.

---

**Comments**. Few notes collected from comments.

Sometimes you see this kind of code:

```
while (Console.In.Peek() != -1)
   yield return Console.ReadLine();
```

It works only if console input is redirected, when input is line buffered then it'll end immediately after first line. Nice and short but simply it doesn't work. If you really really love LINQ and you can't live without one-line functions then you may do this:

```
static IEnumerable<string> ReadAllInputs() {
    return Enumerable.Range(0, Int32.MaxValue)
        .Select(_ => Console.ReadLine())
        .TakeWhile(x => x != null);
}
```

Can we make our *reader* more "generic"? The obvious idea is to use it with files. Maybe yes, maybe not. First of all a console application can have piped input (from file or from another application) then we may not need this *feature*. If we do then we should introduce a separate class `InputReader`, implementation will be different for `ConsoleInputReader`, `FileInputReader` and `HttpInputReader` (for example); one function with a `TextReader` parameter will probably be the worst compromise for all our use-cases. What I'm suggesting is just to don't introduce complexity until you need it...

Comment: That looks nice. Lots of good stuff here, like the string interpolation I did not know about. BTW I saw on StackOverflow a suggestion for writing the generator as `while (Console.In.Peek() >= 0) yield return Console.ReadLine();` Not sure if it's preferable.

Comment: @RayToal Personally I think a better generator would be `IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(TextReader reader) { while(reader.Peek() != -1) { yield return reader.ReadLine(); } }` because it's more generalised and could be used as `ReadLines(Console.In)` or `ReadLines(File.OpenText(path))`. I.e. by using `TextReader`, the method does not have to care about the origin of its input, merely that it is presented as a `TextReader`

Comment: @Pharap no, try yourself and you'll see `Console.In.Peek()` doesn't behave like you expect (from default stdin input is line buffered) then it will break after first line. Well, even if it worked in that way (it doesn't) I'd avoid any generalization until it's required (for file input I'd go with `File.ReadAllLines()` instead then I'd need to introduce a class `InputReader` with `ConsoleInputReader` and `FileInputReader`,  not just a function parameter. Too much useless code for 20 lines of code), plus console app may have piped input...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I tested it and it works for command line piping via cmd but fails with the interactive console, so you're right that it's not equivalent to using the `Console` functions, meaning a specialised version would be required for an interactive console. Unfortunately `Console.In` assumes end of input when the char buffer is empty instead of upon `ctrl-z`. I disagree with `File.ReadAllLines()` as that returns an array, which can be memory hungry with larger files. `File.ReadLines()` is better since it returns an `IEnumerable<string>` which can be enumrated lazily.

Comment: @Pharap I agree, for large files (or unknown length...) File.ReadLines() is a much better choice!

Comment: Appreciate all the great comments here. The exercise is part of a "implement the same program in as many languages as possible" effort and yes the constraints of "use standard input" and "consider a word to be a Unicode letter or apostrophe" were given, despite not being a proper indication of what constitutes a word. The different behaviors of `Console.In` with and without redirection, and the ordering-on-printing were particularly interesting and useful.

Answer (score 6):

Starting with your specific questions:

1. Yes, the class is idiomatically wrapped in a namespace. It's not very important for such a small-scale class as this, but that's the accepted way - the global namespace should only have namespaces in it.
2. Neither the main class not method need to be public. They're called by the loader, not by other code.
3. Assuming you're using VS2008 or later, you can use `var` to shorten the declaration syntax. The type is inferred from the right-hand side of the assignment.
   var counts = new SortedDictionary();
4. The more idiomatic way to do the while check would be to remove it from the condition and simply call it twice, once outside the loop and once inside. There's no modern C#ish replacement. Your way is fine too.
5. TryGetValue or ContainsKey/Get combination are still the way to go, but can be easily wrapped in an Extension Method, which can then be used cleanly:
   counts[word] = counts.GetOrDefault(word, 0) + 1;
6. It's a simple, clear loop. No real need to improve it. If you want, you can use string.Join to create one big string and print it out, but there's no real gain.
7. What would you be using LINQ for here? LINQ is for querying, and you're not doing too much of that here. You *could* write a method using iterators that returns the next line from the console as an `IEnumerable<string>`, and call LINQ functions on it, but it won't be clearer or better performing.

And additionally:

8. One thing I've developed an allergy for over the years is calls to `ToUpper/ToLower`. In 90% of cases, it's done just to do a case insensitive comparison, which is usually a bad idea - it creates new copies of the string, which means memory and GC pressure. If you don't care about representation, just write a case insensitive regex and keep the original strings intact:
   Regex.Matches(line, wordRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
   Also, make sure your dictionary is case-insensitive as well, as @t3chb0t reminds me in the comments:
   SortedDictionary counts = new SortedDictionary(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
9. I'm not sure a a SortedDictionary makes sense here. It has a significantly slower Insert performance than a regular dictionary, and it's not as if you need to access it *sorted* during insertion. I would create a regular `Dictionary<string,int>`, and after processing is done, sort it once.

Comment: Thanks. Re LINQ, well maybe not LINQ necessarily, but whatever C# has for processing streams with mapping, filtering, grouping, and ordering. Regarding #8, I want to count words like "For" and "for" as the same. How to do this without lowercasing?

Comment: I've added the case-insensitive Regex line to the answer.

Comment: And regarding LINQ - I can't think of a LINQ/stream processing version that won't be less readable and more complex than this code.

Comment: I tried your regex suggestion but in a test file containing one `For` and two `for`s I got each version counted. I wanted to get 3 `for`s. I decided on `while ((line = Console.ReadLine()?.ToLower()) != null)` Does that look idiomatic? Not sure if it is more or less readable.

Comment: A case insensitive regex in this case is not enough, you also need a case insensitive dictionary so you should create it with a different constructor and specify the StringComparer.

Comment: Yes the insensitive compare is the thing I missed.

Answer (score 1):

The following:

```
    string line;
    while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        line = line.ToLower();
        foreach (Match m in wordRegex.Matches(line))
        {
            String word = m.Value;
            int count;
            counts.TryGetValue(word, out count);
            counts[word] = ++count;
        }
    }
```

Could be changed to:

```
for(string line = Console.ReadLine(); line != null; line = Console.ReadLine())
{
        line = line.ToLower();
        foreach (Match m in wordRegex.Matches(line))
        {
            string word = m.Value;
            int count = 0;
            counts.TryGetValue(word, out count);
            counts[word] = count + 1;
        }
}
```

Note that `string` should almost always be all lowercase. Note that `count + 1` is preferred here because changing the state of the variable `count` is not the primary intention, the primary intention is the assignment of the value of `count + 1` to an entry in `counts`.

In C#6 you can use the new null-conditional to reduce `line = Console.ReadLine(); /*...*/ line = line.ToLower()`to `line = Console.ReadLine()?.ToLower()`. The latter is equivalent to `string temp = Console.Readline(); line = (temp == null) ? temp : temp.ToLower();`

Other than that I recommend using the `Enumerable` based techniques mentioned in other answers or at least generalising your solution to the `StringReader` class rather than aiming it specifically at the `Console` class. Your solution can then be directed at the standard input stream by using `TextReader reader = Console.In;` or `SolveProblem(Console.In);`, and subsequently directed at a given file by using `TextReader reader = File.OpenText(path);` or `SolveProblem(File.OpenText(path));`. If you choose a method based on enumerating the lines via an IEnumerable however, note that `File.ReadLines(path);` returns an `IEnumerable<string>` that can be enumerated via a `foreach`.